# Differences between "Fluent Assertions" and "Should Assertion Library"

Tags: .net, unit-testing

- Can someone point the differences?

The above is really my question, but if you can also share your experience with them and why you use one or the other.

Comment: Some comparison details can be found at https://dotnet.libhunt.com/compare-shouldly-vs-fluentassertions

Answer (score 27):

They are just two different libraries, so just look at the features, and especially at the reporting capabilities and take your pick.

As I am the author of ***Fluent Assertions***, I'm obviously biased. Regardless, I take big pride in the effort we've been putting in making the error messages as clear as possible so that we can keep you out of the debugger hell.

Comment: It would be in particular interesting to hear from the author, which features of your library are better than in competitors library.

Comment: I would say that the structural comparison API is one of the most powerful features of Fluent Assertions that the other libraries (still) don't have. AFAIK, there's nothing in Shouldly that Fluent Assertions does not have as well. See also https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/#object-graph-comparison

Comment: The documentation has moved to https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/

Comment: @DennisDoomen It (now) exists in Shouldly as well: `actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't compare to what Fluent Assertions has to [offer](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/). It took us years to get where it is now.

Answer (score 3):

SA-'s example of FluentAssertions is incorrect. The examples should be:

- FluentAssertions: `variable.Should().Be(10);`
- Shouldly: `variable.ShouldBe(10);`

As you can see there is barely any difference in usage for this simple example.

I've found FluentAssertions to be the slightly more hands on, but more powerful library, with Shouldly lacking some features. The error messages of Shouldly are indeed a bit better with using natural language, but I wouldn't go as far as say they're less technical.