# How to choose between Shouldly and FluentAssertions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assertion, fluent-assertions, shouldly

What are the differences (if any) between Shouldly and FluentAssertions?

Can either do anything that the other one can't? Or are they functionally the same with just a different syntax?

*The only [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300507/differences-between-fluent-assertions-and-should-assertion-library) I can find on this is from 2013.
It's now 2022 and both products have moved on a lot since then so I figured I would re-ask the question.*

Comment: I'm unaware of any recent detailed feature comparison. (A not so detailed [comparison from 2018](https://blog.safnet.com/archive/2018/12/03/assertion-comparisons/)) FluentAssertions is more mature and more extensible. Whereas Shouldly is more lightweight and has less features.

Comment: Well, Shouldly has had a VS crashing bug for me for about 2 years now, that was fixed over a year ago, and yet it still hasn't been released. I think the project is dead.